# Comparing Session Variables in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, compare, session-variables

I am trying to create a menu where based on the users access level in the database the user will be shown one of two different menus.

Right now my code is as follows:

```
if($_SESSION['acl'] == "Administrator"){
    echo $_SESSION['acl'];
    echo "You are an administrator";
}
{
    echo $_SESSION['acl'];
    echo "You are a basic user";
}
```

My issue is that the test for the if statement always fails and goes directly to the else section.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is you don't have an `else` section, you forgot to write the word `else`! As a result, the bottom code chunk is **always** being executed, which is why you're always seeing it.

Regarding why the top `if()` statement, which checks if the user is an administrator, is never called: this can be that you are accessing a session variable without first calling `session_start()` at the top of your code. If that's not it, make sure you correctly set that session variable earlier.

```
// start the session (required on all pages using session variables)
session_start();

// I assume that for debug, you print the session variable
echo $_SESSION['acl'];

if($_SESSION['acl'] == "Administrator"){
    echo "You are an administrator";
}
else
{
    echo "You are a basic user";
}
```

Just a suggestion: I assume the code `echo $_SESSION['acl'];` is just there for debug. I moved it under the `session_start()` because this way, it's still always being called, but you're not writing it twice.

Comment: I was just about to write that.  assuming it isnt just a typo when posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

With that same logic it'd be something like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['acl'])){
    if($_SESSION['acl'] == "Administrator"){
        echo 'You are an administrator';
        }
    else{
        echo 'You are a basic user';
        }
}else{
    echo 'Session "acl" was not set';
    }
```